# SSH Questions.... Calling all SA's

Tags: linux, ssh

I am a programming and not a SA but in the current firm I am in I have to do some lite SA work so I have a question..

I have server a number of servers (really VM's) which I ssh into.. I installed my public-key to them so I don't have to remember the passwords.

If someone changes the password to one of the servers will my ssh still work?

Comment: Why would someone change your password without informing you? It seems like there might be some other non-technical issues here.

Comment: @EEAA, because lots of people ignore the common security wisdom, and setup shared accounts for accessing resources.  Regrettably, this is very common from I have seen.

Comment: @Zoredache - Ugh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If someone changes the password to one of the servers will my ssh still work?

Yes you will still have access unless:

- they disable key-based authentication
- they remove your key
- they remove the account you have setup your key under

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you will still be able to SSH to the servers if a password change occurs. The SSH key framework does not rely on the password infrastructure.